# How to stop coil burners from cycling off and on

Tags: electrical

I have a Frigidaire coiltop stove. The burners cycle off and on. I would like them to stay on until I turn them off, can that be changed on my stove?

Comment: If it's cycling on and off at full heat, you have a malfunction, either in the thermal timer which controls cycling for lower temperatures or in the control board which implements those cycles in many newer cooktops (especially those with electronic controls)

Answer (score 4):

Painful though this is, the correct answer is **learn to cook with electric**.  The stove works differently and you have to learn to deal with that.  Electric coils have only two settings (*on* and *off*), so it cycles between the two to maintain the desired temperature.

Also, I found that to quickly arrest heat (say, when something is boiling over), the answer is to quickly move the pot off the burner.  Obvious though it may be in hindsight, it was a real eye-opener at the time.

I do see where it has its charms, for instance if an unattended pot runs dry on an electric burner, the electric will simply hold it at target temperature and not destroy the pot.

Answer (score 0):

Turn them up to full power and they will stay on,  half power is half on half off. it's just how they work.